# Converting a postgresql database to mysql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I've been a'Googling and there's all sorts of various forms of crazy ideas out there, but, dear Stack Overflow geniuses, is there a stable, reliable form of converting a postgresql database to a mysql database on Linux?

Comment: PostgreSQL has [DbLink](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html), but it's only for connecting to other PostgreSQL instances.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a program which connects to both databases and reads records from PostGres, inserting to MySQL.  You'll have to do the schemas by hand.

This is a pretty common way to do database migrations...  An automated tool would be nice, but the differences in functionality are so subtle that I'm not sure one exists.

Comment: This is also what i fear i'd have to use... However, seeing as that seems the only solution, i expected to find at least some basic tool to build one...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can work with a Data Pump tool in order to import information from ADO-compatible sources into Mysql. You will have to double check with stored procedures as an example... but tables, fields and data could be imported - in my experience - using those tools with no problem. I suggest you to check http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/datapump and try.. rgds.